# Как склонять название праздника Рождества Христова?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, прописная-строчная

Как написать правильно?

С праздником Рождество Христово или Рождества Христова?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно "**с праздником Рождества Христова**", "**праздник Рождества Христова**".

Это выражение отмечено во многих словарях. Например, его можно найти [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%EA%EE%EB%FF%E4%E0).

Comment: Я оставила маленькие буквы специально. Если спрашивают, как правильно писать **РХ** — большими буквами,— вполне возможно, что НЕ знают и про заглавные-строчные. Поэтому и дала отдельную метку. В Вашей формулировке вопроса такая метка не нужна.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Прошу извинить, я не заметил новую метку. А как же "презумпция невиновности"? Да ещё в праздник :) Может оставим как есть, в том числе с меткой — на всякий случай? (Но я не настаиваю.)

Comment: Ну, если только ради праздника. Шучу. На Мете я уже всех поздравила.  P.S. Я живу почти на море — у нас праздничный шторм... Пусть в **душе** у всех будет покой.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо! Вам тоже мои лучшие пожелания! (И всем, кто заглянет сюда по случаю праздника :)

Answer (score 1):

Праздник называется **Рождество Христово**. Но поздравляют обычно  так: **с праздником** (каким?) **Рождества Христова**.  Форма Р.п. является несогласованным определением.

В других случаях возможны **варианты** (в том числе "приложение + название в И.п."):

**Рождество́ Христо́во**  — один из главных христианских праздников. Как рассказать в интересной и доступной форме детям **о празднике Рождество**. Миллионы православных христиан во всем мире отмечают один из самых главных церковных праздников - **Рождество Христово.**